# How to change the tab index in avalonia ui

Tags: avaloniaui

In Avalonia Ui,
I have multiple layouts in my ui and I want a very specific tab order,
something like

```
<TextBox Tabindex="2">
<StackPanel>
 <TextBox Tabindex="1">
</StackPanel>
<TextBox Tabindex="0">
```

that would result in using the tab-key cycling from bottom to top.
Is this possible? I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. `KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex` is not implmented yet: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/3025.
You have some limited Control using the functions provided in `KeyboardNavigation` and by using another control, for example a `DockPanel` or a `Relative Panel`.

Here is a very basic example for how you can use a `DockPanel` to do what you wish to:

```xml
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Name="TabOrderConatiner">
    <TextBox Name="First" Tag="2" DockPanel.Dock="Top"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="Third" Tag="0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="Second" Tag="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top"></TextBox>
</DockPanel>
```

However it is like I said above limited compared to what `TabIndex` can provide.

Apart from that you should also be able to set the first *TabItem* when the container becomes active like that from your code-behind:

```cs
var tabOrderContainer = this.FindControl<DockPanel>("TabOrderConatiner");
var initialElement = this.FindControl<TextBox>("Third");

KeyboardNavigation.SetTabOnceActiveElement(tabOrderContainer, initialElement);
```

but I did not manage to get this to work...